# detect the parent who open uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have two different scenarios that call the same uiviewcontroller,
scenario 1:
in the main uiviewcontroller clicking a button creates a dummy navigator and present it like this:

```
UINavigationController* dummyNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[dummyNavigation addChildViewController:bViewController];
[self presentViewController:dummyNavigation animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

scenario 2:
in the main uiviewcontroller clicking a button open a uitableviewcontroller in it every click on a row open `bViewController` like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bViewController animated:NO];
```

I've set the navigation bar of bViewController to hidden

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

and created a button to replace the back button of the navigation with this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**the problem:** in both scenarios the back button code returns to the main `uiviewcontroller` but in scenario 2 its expected to return to the `uitableviewcontroller`

Answer (score -1):

Check when dismissing, if it is in a navigation controller then pop otherwise dismiss.

```
if (self.navigationController) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: your answer is incorrect since `if (self.navigationController)` is **always true** in scenario 1 there is a dummyNavigation and scenario 2 its the uitableviewcontroller's navigationcontroller